# Isn't PDFBOX2.0 supported JDK 1.5?

Tags: java, pdfbox, environment, java-5

I want to use PDFBOX 2.0 in JDK 1.5 environment.

I might read that PDFBOX is supported in JDK 1.5 environment.

In JDK 1.5, I have done test. but it is unsupported.

So I want to know weather PDFBOX 2.0 is supported by JDK 1.5 environment.

Answer (score 2):

from the doc (https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/migration.html) : **PDFBox 2.0.0 requires at least Java 6 Packages**

```
Migration to PDFBox 2.0.0
Environment

PDFBox 2.0.0 requires at least Java 6 Packages

There are some significant changes to the package structure of PDFBox:

Jempbox is no longer supported and was removed in favour of Xmpbox
all examples were moved to the new package "pdfbox-examples"
all commandline tools were moved to the new package "pdfbox-tools"
all debugger related stuff was moved to the new package "pdfbox-debugger"
the new package "debugger-app" provides a standalone pre built binary for the debugger
```

Answer (score 0):

PDFBox 2.0 supports 1.6 and upwards I believe. The older versions of PDFBox however do support 1.5.